# Trouble with multiple-sectioned TableView in Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, core-data

I apologize in advance if this is confusing. I'm new to Swift with no prior experience and learning.

Basically, I have a UITableView that pulls its data form another viewController with four text fields. The data is saved and added to the tableView (only displaying the two of the fields in the cell). When the cell is selected it segues back to the viewController and adds the data in the appropriate text fields. This also utilized CoreData and NSFetchResultsController. All of this is working properly so far, just wanted to give a little back ground on whats going on.

The Problem...
I am trying to get the tableView to display the data in two sections. I want the first section (section 0) to display the data added to the list created by adding the text fields on the viewController. However, the tableView adds first row as the first section (with the header correct) and then adds the second row (and on) as the second section (section 1)(with section header). I want to add all new items from the viewController to section 0, leaving section 1 blank for when I figure out how to cross items off section 0 and move to section 1 by selecting the row (Coming in the future).

I am new to this site as well and could not figure out how to post my code. If anyone needs to look through it you may have to walk me through adding it. Also, I have trouble converting Objective C to Swift please keep that in mind while answering. Thank you!! and I apologize for being difficult.

(tableView Controller "SList")

```
class ShoppingList: UIViewController, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate { 

    let moc = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext

    var frc : NSFetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController()

    func itemFetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest{

        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "SList")
        let primarySortDescription = NSSortDescriptor(key: "slitem", ascending: true)
        let secondarySortDescription = NSSortDescriptor(key: "slcross", ascending: true)
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [primarySortDescription, secondarySortDescription]
        return fetchRequest
    }

    func getFetchRequetController() ->NSFetchedResultsController{

        frc = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: itemFetchRequest(), managedObjectContext: moc, sectionNameKeyPath: "slitem", cacheName: nil)
        return frc
    }  

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!


    @IBAction func AddNew(sender: AnyObject) {

        frc = getFetchRequetController()
        frc.delegate = self

        do {
            try frc.performFetch()
        } catch _ {
            print("Failed to perform inital fetch.")
            return
        }
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        frc = getFetchRequetController()
        frc.delegate = self

        do {
            try frc.performFetch()
        } catch _ {
            print("Failed to perform inital fetch.")
            return
        }

        self.tableView.reloadData()

        //TableView Background Color
        self.tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        tableView.reloadData()
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
        self.tableView.separatorColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    }

    override func viewDidDisappear(animated: Bool) {

        frc = getFetchRequetController()
        frc.delegate = self

        do {
            try frc.performFetch()
        } catch _ {
            print("Failed to perform inital fetch.")
            return
        }
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }

    //TableView Data
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        let managedObject:NSManagedObject = frc.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! NSManagedObject
        moc.deleteObject(managedObject)
        do {
            try moc.save()
        } catch _ {
            print("Failed to save.")
            return
        }
    }

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

        let numberOfSections = frc.sections?.count
        return numberOfSections!
    }

    //table section headers
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String?{
        let sectionHeader = "Items - #\(frc.sections![section].numberOfObjects)"
        let sectionHeader1 = "Crossed Off Items - #\(frc.sections![section].numberOfObjects)"
        if (section == 0) {
            return sectionHeader
        }
        if (section == 1){
            return sectionHeader1
        }else{
        return nil
    }
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        let numberOfRowsInSection = frc.sections?[section].numberOfObjects
        return numberOfRowsInSection!
    }


    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
        let items = frc.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! SList
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        cell.textLabel?.text = "\(items.slitem!) - Qty: \(items.slqty!)"
        cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(23)

        return cell
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }


    func controllerDidChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController)      {
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
    //segue to add/edit
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {

        if segue.identifier == "edit" {

            let cell = sender as! UITableViewCell
            let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForCell(cell)
            let SListController:SLEdit = segue.destinationViewController as! SLEdit
            let items:SList = frc.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath!) as! SList
            SListController.item = items
        }
    }
}
```

(ViewController "SLEdit")

```
class SLEdit: UIViewController {

    let moc = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext


    @IBOutlet weak var slitem: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var sldesc: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var slqty: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var slprice: UITextField!


    var item: SList? = nil


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if item != nil{
            slitem.text = item?.slitem
            sldesc.text = item?.sldesc
            slqty.text = item?.slqty
            slprice.text = item?.slprice
        }

        // "x" Delete Feature
        self.slitem.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewMode.WhileEditing
        self.sldesc.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewMode.WhileEditing
        self.slqty.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewMode.WhileEditing
        self.slprice.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewMode.WhileEditing
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    func dismissVC() {
        navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
    }

    @IBAction func saveButton(sender: AnyObject) {

        if item != nil {
            edititems()
        } else {
            createitems()
        }

        dismissVC()
    }


    func createitems() {

        let entityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("SList", inManagedObjectContext: moc)


        let item = SList(entity: entityDescription!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: moc)

        item.slitem = slitem.text
        item.sldesc = sldesc.text
        item.slqty = slqty.text
        item.slprice = slprice.text

        if slitem.text == nil{
            createitems()

        }else{
            edititems()
        }



        do {
            try moc.save()
        } catch _ {
            return
        }
    }
    func edititems() {
        item?.slitem = slitem.text!
        item?.sldesc = sldesc.text!
        item?.slqty = slqty.text!
        item?.slprice = slprice.text!


        do {
            try moc.save()
        } catch {
            return
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add some code, so we can see what you have tried so far?

Comment: finally figured it out...it kind of messed up but first and second are the tableview controller third is the view controller that inputs the information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem lies in your FRC configuration:

```
frc = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: itemFetchRequest(), managedObjectContext: moc, sectionNameKeyPath: "slitem", cacheName: nil)
```

Because `sectionNameKeyPath` is `slitem`, the FRC creates a new section for each different value of `slitem`.

If the `slcross` attribute is used to indicate that the item has been crossed off the list, specify that as the `sectionNameKeyPath`:

```
frc = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: itemFetchRequest(), managedObjectContext: moc, sectionNameKeyPath: "slcross", cacheName: nil)
```

You will also need to modify the sorting of the fetch request (it MUST be sorted so that all items in a given section are together):

```
let primarySortDescription = NSSortDescriptor(key: "slcross", ascending: true)
let secondarySortDescription = NSSortDescriptor(key: "slitem", ascending: true)
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [primarySortDescription, secondarySortDescription]
```

Comment: Well that pretty much solved it except for 2 issues...1: it throws a error for "A section returned nil value for section name key path 'slcross'. Objects will be placed in unnamed section"...is this because there is nothing in the section until I "cross it off" (by selecting the row in the future) and it adds it to the section? and 2: it does not reload when an item is added/edited. I added tableview.reloadData() to the end of the sectionHeader code but it says it will never be executed.

Comment: Yes, the warning about nil value for sections is because your `SList` items have `slcross = nil`.  Set a default value (false), then when you cross it off you can change it to true.  Regarding the reload problem, you should not need to reinitialise the frc and reperform the fetch in the `AddNew` IBAction, nor in viewDidDisappear.  The frc delegate should handle updating the table.

Comment: Sorry for the delay response. I removed it the reinitialization from the AddNew IBAction and the viewDidDisappear and it wouldn't reload the tableview until I reloaded the simulator (stop then re-ran). Side note...I changed the frc sectionNameKeyPath from "slcross" to nil and it seemed to solve the reloading issue and the heading stays even when nothing is in the list (which is fine). Does this solve it or will this cause problems down the line when I eventually get items to move to that section?

Comment: I assumed (wrongly, it seems) that `slcross` was an attribute that you were using to indicate that an item had been crossed off.  Using `nil` for the `sectionNameKeyPath` will work OK for the time being, but the FRC will only ever put items in the first section.  My suggestion would be to add a boolean attribute to `SLItems` that indicates whether the item has been crossed off.  Whenever you create a new item, set the default value to false, and when you cross off an item, change it to true.  If you specify that attribute as the `sectionNameKeyPath`, the FRC will automatically shuffle....

Comment: the corresponding item from section 0 to section 1.  As to the reloading issue, `reloadData` is rather a blunt instrument, and with a properly configured FRC you shouldn't need to use it.  But having reread your code, I can't see any the problem with the FRC: you are using the minimum FRC delegate method,`controllerDidChangeContent` but that should work.

Comment: Ok, I will have to change the sectionNameKeypath back to "slcross". You are correct with the "slcross" attribute under the Entity "SList" (the same with item, qty, desc, and price). What you are describing is exactly what I want it to do. I am just slowly learning how to get it all working like it's supposed too. I apologize for not understanding just yet. I am basically teaching myself swift as I go along. How do I add the ability to specify true or false on the attribute?